# How can I run nmap scan via multiple proxies (not chained; each proxy will be used for disjoint part of the scan)?

Tags: proxy, nmap, python, scan

How can I run nmap scan via multiple proxies, such that each proxy will actually send only part of the packets?

For example, assuming that a scan sends X requests, and I have Y proxies, I would like that my nmap python script will send X requests, such that each disjoint subset of X/Y requests will be tunneled through different proxy.

Could it be done?

Are there any other tools that can do this?

Comment: From top of my head, loop over each range choosing a new proxy for each, that sounds more a programming question than a security one at all.

Comment: Yes, @Tensibai is right, you need an script to do this I think.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best option is using the proxychains tool for that.

In the configuration file (/etc/proxychains.conf) you can list your proxy servers and then enable the "Random Chain" option. You can find a nice step-by-step on [this tutorial](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-like-pro-evade-detection-using-proxychains-0154619/). Also, if you want to use just ONE proxy each time, set the "chain_len" option to one.

Just a quick tip, when running a nmap scan over proxychains, don't forget to use the flags "-sT -Pn", otherwise your scan may fail.